# How to add aliases in my disjunction using hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm writing a Criteria query using hibernate. I have a DTO object and I have to generate a query using its fields. Everyting seems fine when I create a disjunction like this:

```
Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Item.class);
        c.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.like("buyer", dto.getUser()))
                .add(Restrictions.like("rndEngineer", dto.getUser()))
                .add(Restrictions.like("logistics", dto.getUser()))
                .add(Restrictions.like("qaEngineer", dto.getUser()))
        );
```

But if I add an alias to my query to be able to do this:

```
Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Item.class);
        c.createAlias("wiEngineer", "we");
        c.add(Restrictions.disjunction()
                .add(Restrictions.like("buyer", dto.getUser()))
                .add(Restrictions.like("rndEngineer", dto.getUser()))
                .add(Restrictions.like("logistics", dto.getUser()))
                .add(Restrictions.like("qaEngineer", dto.getUser()))
                .add(Restrictions.like("we.sid", dto.getUser()))
        );
```

the where clause is fine but my result set is missing some elements. I think that Hibernate inner joins we on my item. Can I make Hibernate left join my alias somehow? I googled on it but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Javadoc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) to the rescue:

> Criteria createAlias(String associationPath,
>                        String alias,
>                        int joinType)
>                        throws HibernateException
>
> Join an association using the specified join-type, assigning an alias to the joined association.
>
> The joinType is expected to be one of CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN (the default),
>   CriteriaSpecification.FULL_JOIN, or CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN.

Why use Google when you have the javadoc and the Hibernate reference documentation available?

Comment: Lesson learned: Check javadoc a second time before asking dumb questions. Thanks!